# How does the function pcf.ppp() differ from pcfinhom() in spatstat?

Tags: r, spatstat

In spatstat the function pcf.ppp() estimates the pair correlation function g(r) by kernel smoothing. Hence, "the estimation of the intensity also plays an important role in the estimation of the pair correlation function" (Illian et al. 2008, p. 232).

The function pcfinhom() estimates the inhomogeneous pair correlation function of a point pattern that does not have a uniform density of points, using kernel methods.

So, my question is: Both functions estimates the pair correlation function g(r) taking the intensity of the points into account. How are the to methods different?

Since pcf.ppp() includes an estimate of the intensity, does it require a uniform density of points?

Any insights in this matter would be most appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the process is assumed to be homogeneous (so the intensity is a single constant value) you should use `pcf.ppp()` if the process is inhomogeneous (so the intensity is a spatially varying function) you should use `pcfinhom()`.

It is correct that `pcf.ppp()` uses the technique of kernel smoothing, but that is not to estimate the intensity, but rather to smooth out the pairwise distances involved in the calculation of the pcf. In this function the intensity is estimated to be the constant `lambda = npoints(X)/area(Window(X))`.

Comment: Ok. Thank you! Just so that I understand, in the function pcfinhom() the arguments 'kernel' and 'bw' are related to the kernel smoothing involved in the calculation of the pairwise distances whereas the argument 'lambda' is related to the estimation of the inhomogeneous intensity? Also, if 'lambda' is omitted, is it estimated similarly to how 'lambda' is estimated in the function Kinhom()?